# Leaflet dm and semicircle

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to measure and show angle using semicircle library. It would measure angle between two vertices being drawn with PM Leaflet library.

Measuring angles is good, however, drawn semicircle line and the angle lines are not overlapping. I noticed they are overlapping perfectly near 0,0 coordinates but if I try to apply this action near poles, as you suppose, distortion is great. [image: Drawing circle and two lines]

My code for capturing angle and creating circle.

```
function captureMove(evt, p1, p2){
  let firstAngle = Math.atan2(p2[0] - p1[0], p2[1] - p1[1]) * 180 / Math.PI - 90;
  let secondAngle = Math.atan2(evt.latlng.lat - p1[0], evt.latlng.lng - p1[1]) * 180 / Math.PI - 90;
  firstAngle < 0? firstAngle +=360:''
  secondAngle < 0? secondAngle +=360:''
  rightClick? createCircle(p1, secondAngle, firstAngle): createCircle(p1, firstAngle, secondAngle);
}
```

Creating circle:

```
   function createCircle(p1, ang1, ang2){
  let noOfLayers = temLayer.getLayers();
  if(noOfLayers.length > 1){
    temLayer.removeLayer(noOfLayers[1]);
  } 
  ang1 < ang2?ang1+=360:''
  var circle = L.semiCircle(p1, {
      radius: 1000,
        startAngle: 360 - ang1,
        stopAngle: 360 - ang2,
        color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)',
    });
  temLayer.addLayer(circle);
};
```

What could cause this? I realize it is projection distortion. But how to solve this?

Comment: It's hard to guess from your code what parameters p1, p2 and evt represent. But anyway, problem probably comes from using geographical coordinates for angle caclulation. Use pixel coordinates instead and it should be ok.

Comment: Did you succeed with pixel coordinates?

Comment: Yes. I made it with this method map.latLngToContainerPoint(); Thank you!

Comment: Then publish your solution as answer so others with similar problems may profit from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved with method `map.latLngToContainerPoint();` applied on the points(p1 and p2). I had to convert geographical to the pixel coordinates. 
Thanks to the TomazicM comment :)